# Output HTML on select change in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Give me examples jquery select value echo content as:

[image]

- if select item 1 echo div content 1
- if select item 2 echo div content 2

etc.

My code :

```
<select>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 1">Iteam 1</option>
  <!-- ....more -->
  <option value="Item more">Item more</option>
</select>

<div class="value1">Content for select item 1</div>
<div class="value2">Content for select item 2</div>
.....
<div class="valuem">Content for select item more</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Bind the change event, check the class selector, http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html

```
 <select>
    <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="Item 5">Item 5</option>
    <option value="Item 6">Item 6</option>
</select>
<span class="response"></span>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(".response").text("This is content "+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seLt9/)

Comment: how to echo div html. Thanks

Comment: div and span are sample <div class="response"></div>

Comment: i'm working with select echo contact: yahoo icon - skype icon, enmail icon. how to get its

Comment: post your html on jsfiddle and send me the link

Comment: @AmauryLoiseau where r u from? Vietnam?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
       $("#result").text("This is content "+$(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: text() would be more appropriate

Comment: Give me examples full code, i can't uses jquey :( pls

Comment: I have updated my code. You can put this in your HTML and you should be fine. Preferably place it below </body>. Also changed it to text() as it is indeed more appropriate.

Comment: Give me code echo div, and defaults is echo value. i'm select it's echo value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $("#contentItem").text("The new content is " + $(this).val());
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>   
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>    
</select>    
<div id="contentItem">
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F5h8L/)

Comment: How to get `text("The new content is " + $(this).val());` to img, text link, ... Thanks

Comment: $('p').text('My awesome text'); - this will set the text to 'My awesome text' for each `<p>` tag on the page.

Comment: how to: i'm selcet item 1: echo: image and text. Thanks

Comment: So you want me to print out text 'Image and text' or the actual image and some text? If the latter, please give me the HTML code you want me to output.

Comment: i want echo if select value 1 echo: <Div class="text">Skype: <img src="/skype-icon.png"> - Phone: +00000000 </div> and value 2 so on . Thanks

Comment: give me value skype & phone different when i'm select value : http://jsfiddle.net/dinhtv/4LEPF/2/ .thanks

Comment: martynas. Thanks for support. how to default always echo value 1.I have to pick it out last.

Comment: No problem. Just put the functionality of the change function into a separate function and call that function when page loads.